# Setting up my first SQL Server cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I've been working with SQL Server for about 6 years and have completed a couple of certification exams so I consider myself reasonably knowledgeable.

I am however, about to spec and build my first SQL Server failover cluster. I know how it works, I've read about it over and over...

My question to you lot is: What advice/warnings would you give to someone in my position?

Did you find certain aspects of setup more tricky than others? Would I be best advised to upgrade from SQL Server 2008 r2 to 2012?

My loose plan is to use my company's existing HP blade enclosure to house 2 x HP servers with plenty of RAM/Cores - just a 2-node cluster with either a mirror or AOAG for added redundancy.

Thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't use the same blade chassis for both blades. They should be split up among different chassis, racks, etc, as the point of clustering is to *NOT* have a single point of failure. Make sure you trace everything from the storage to the networking and power to make sure you're still not putting all of your eggs in one basket or making the design more costly than it needs to be.

Comment: Now that is good thinking.

Comment: Do you think this provides sufficient hardware redundancy for a SQL cluster: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/blades/info/what-is-a-blade.html ?

Comment: It all depends on the workload you're attempting to have it run. You can cluster two desktops if you would like (not that I would actually do this). If you've an idea of workload then choosing hardware shouldn't bee too terribly difficult. I would project the hardware needs to encompass at least 3 years but more like 5 for a typical IT refresh cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a new deployment then why not upgrade to the latest version of the software? 2014 has many [benefits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411.aspx) over 2008 and 2012.

The install is simple if you have configured windows clusters before. I would recommend windows 2012R2 as clustering is a little easier with features like network teaming and the automatic quorum level settings.

One of the hardest things to get right can be the LUNs that you configure on the SAN especially if you're using SAN level snapshotting.

Comment: I'd love to go with 2014 but the software vendor doesn't support anything above 2008 r2 for their database. Currently trying to devise a case for upgrading to at least 2012.

Comment: Regarding the LUNs, hopefully my SAN admin will handle that.

Comment: Do you have to use traditional failover clustering or would SQL 2012 availability groups be an option?  They are share-nothing so you don't need to use shared san storage.  It opens a lot of options for you.

Comment: Hi Alf, the recovery time/recovery point objective as defined by management is one minute, which means SQL Clustering is the correct solution. 2012 HA would work nicely alongside clustering though. I'm basically trying to prove that using an HP c7000 blade enclosure for both nodes sort of defeats the purpose of a cluster, as Mat said before.

Comment: You said RTO is 1 min so clustering is solution I hope you are aware that, Just SQL server cluster will not provide you SQL database redundancy. It will provide OS redundancy as a fact you still need to gof or Always on or mirroring or logshipping for database redundancy( if DB gets corrupted Cluster will not help)